# What else can SQL Server Management Studio do?

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL Server Management Studio. In my company it is used just to sink data from source table to convert into predefined format, for that I use few queries in query table.

Please guide what else SQL Server Management Studio can help me?

Comment: An easier option would have been to search on google. Read this link [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174219(v=sql.120).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SQL Server Management Studio includes the following general features:**

- Supports most administrative tasks for SQL Server.
- A single, integrated environment for SQL Server Database Engine management and authoring.
- Dialogs for managing objects in the SQL Server Database Engine, Analysis Services, and Reporting Services, that allows you to execute your actions immediately, send them to a Code Editor, or script them for later execution.
- A common scheduling dialog that allows you to perform action of the management dialogs at a later time.
- Exporting and importing SQL Server Management Studio server registration from one Management Studio environment to another.
- Save or print XML Showplan or Deadlock files generated by SQL Server Profiler, review them later, or send them to administrators for analysis.
- A new error and informational message box that presents much more information, allows you to send Microsoft a comment about the messages, allows you to copy messages to the clipboard, and allows you to easily e-mail the messages to your support team.
- An integrated Web browser for quick browsing of MSDN or online help.
- Integration of Help from online communities.

Comment: thanks Lyah for your detail explanation, can you pls also correct below SQL Query 'select * from FINANCIAL_DATA_NARRATION where ACCOUNT='7311001,73211001'', as its give msg **Invalid object name**

Comment: If ACCOUNT is **Int**, try this Query SELECT * FROM FINANCIAL_DATA_NARRATION WHERE ACCOUNT IN (7311001,73211001)

Comment: **OR** If ACCOUNT is **varchar()**, try this Query SELECT * FROM FINANCIAL_DATA_NARRATION WHERE ACCOUNT IN ('7311001','73211001')

Comment: thanks column is nvarchar() ..... so both are working. :-)